# HP Proliant DL-385 G6, 1-beep, Health LED red, no screen output

Tags: hp-proliant, custom-errors

When attempting to start-up an HP Proliant DL-385 G6, I hear 1 long beep and the front panel of the server lights up amber.  Internally everything is green.

Looking up the HP support website, there is no 1 beep error message.  Can anyone suggest why the external device LEDs are amber and the heartbeat LED continually blinks red? (1Hz on then off)

https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c01702138#N10034

Considering the age of this server I'd expect this detail to be easily found online.  I'm guessing it's a critical error, as nothing is shown on the monitor, despite the server fans kicking in happily.

There don't appear to be any lights on the HDDs.

Answer (score 0):

Found that the risers were not seated correctly. Removing from the metal casing and manually seating them immediately fixed the issue.